# Can I use the word Paramount ? if not What would be a suitable alternative?

Tags: synonyms

"Pressure paramounted when I was impeded from attending the final examinations of the second semester"

Comment: It is a perfectly good adjective, but using it as a verb sounds strange to the native speaker's ear (see [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=paramount_ADJ%2Cparamount_VERB&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3)); and is unlikely to convey clear meaning. Maybe pressure *mounted* or *reached its maximum* or *zenith.*

Comment: Perhaps "Pressure was exacerbated as/when ...".

Comment: @Abdullah Lizu "Pressure was at its peak/highest as I..."

Comment: If "paramount" were a verb, then I think it would probably mean "reached its maximum", as @BrianDonovan suggested.  If that's the meaning you want, then "peaked" seems an appropriate option.

Answer (score 3):

The only citation for ***paramount*** as a verb in the OED is dated 1699 (obsolete and rare!) ... (http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/137536?isAdvanced=false&result=2&rskey=7cqC57&)

Depending on the sense you want you could use *build*, *intensify* or *become intolerable*:

*Pressure **built** / **intensified** / **became intolerable** when I was impeded from attending the final examinations of the second semester.*

Comment: “The pressure became intolerable” is much better. But I still don’t like “I was impeded from.” How? Why? Who impeded you? Why not tell the story instead of describing the result in an academic way? If it was due to illness, for example, then I would suggest “The pressure became intolerable when illness prevented me from attending the final examinations of the second semester.”

Comment: @SimonWhite - I agree.  But the OP asks only about *paramount*.

Answer (score 1):

As @Dan explained, paramount is not used as a verb. And a lot of good suggestions have been offered to replace it. My 2 cents is the noun *pressure* is a good choice, but the noun [**stress**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/stress) works better in your context which means:

> A state of mental or emotional strain or tension resulting from
>   adverse or demanding circumstances:

Your example:

> I was under **great** (or [tremendous, unbearable or intolerable)](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=under+tremendous+stress%2Cunder+unbearable+stress%2C+under+intolerable+stress&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cunder%20tremendous%20stress%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cunder%20unbearable%20stress%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cunder%20intolerable%20stress%3B%2Cc0) stress when I couldn't attend the final
>   examinations of the second semester.

Using the adjective **great** is [far more popular](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=under+tremendous+stress%2Cunder+unbearable+stress%2Cunder+intolerable+stress%2C+under+great&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cunder%20tremendous%20stress%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cunder%20unbearable%20stress%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cunder%20intolerable%20stress%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cunder%20great%3B%2Cc0) than using *tremendous, unbearable* or *intolerable*. Also, you could consider replacing **was under great stress** with **felt stressed out**.

Using **Stress increased exponentially, sharply or dramatically when...** or **Stress became unbearable when...**, etc is another option if you want to use *stress* as a subject.

As Simon White commented to Dan's answer, *was impeded* is not idiomatic especially when it is used without *by an agent* at the end of the sentence.

[Oxford Online Dictionary, Ngram Viewer]